# is it possible to allow delete query only if there is primary key in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

My use-case is to delete a row from the table only with the unique key (or Primary key) to assure that the right data is getting deleted.

I want to prevent delete queries if there are fields other than the Primary key or unique key.

Let's say 'id' is the auto-incremented primary key in my table than,

```
delete from my_table where id = 10
```

This should work but,

```
delete from my_table where first_name = "John"
```

this should be blocked for all users of MySQL. can we achieve this just with MySQL? I know, I can add multiple checks with my backend language in my logic part but I want to check if it is possible to handle on MySQL part?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, MySQL does almost have such a mode.  It is implemented using `sql_safe_updates`.  Specifically:

> If this variable is enabled, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements that do not use a key in the `WHERE` clause or a `LIMIT` clause produce an error.

The definition of "key" here may not match your definition of a key.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates) for more information.

You can set this when you start the MySQL client using [`--safe_updates`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates) or by running:

```
set sql_safe_updates=1;
```

Comment: This will still allow `delete from my_table where first_name = "John" limit 1000` (where 1000 can be any high number.....)

Comment: @Luuk Correct. I have checked that `sql_safe_update` is not the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is flawed because I can trick MySQL into thinking that I am using a primary key like so --
`DELETE FROM table WHERE id <> 0;`